# Minimum similarity for a FuzzyLikeThis query

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

How can I specify the minimum similarity for a flt query in NEST? I am searching for a method to call but I can find nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "fuzzy_like_this" : {
        "like_text" : "text like this one",
        "min_similarity" : 1
    }
}
```

Comment: I meant a method to call in NEST library. Modified the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
 q.FuzzyLikeThis(f => f.LikeText(keywords)
                    .OnFields("fieldName")
                    .Boost(1)
                    .MaxQueryTerms(25)                  
                    .MinimumSimilarity(1)
```